# What does this ms outlook red colored badge (icon) mean?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, pictures

[image: MS Outlook screenshot]

Here in the image I have pointed to the badge icon.. Do anyone know what this means?

Below is the badge icon from above screenshot..

[image: Badge Icon in outlook]

Comment: What happens if you hover over it or click it?

Comment: On hover outlook doesn't show any tooltip..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### What does the red coloured badge mean?

[What do the Outlook icons mean?](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/icons.htm) lists all of the icons in outlook and explains what they mean.

The icon you are referring to is in the [Security](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/icons.htm#Security) section and indicates that the message has a **Valid Signature**:

> [image]

If you **Open** the message and then click on this icon you can find more information about the digital signature.

See [View a digital signature in a signed e-mail message](https://support.office.com/client/How-to-tell-if-a-digital-signature-is-trustworthy-0464f8ab-fefa-4bc7-af0d-e07a12f7097e#bm3) for more information.

Source [What do the Outlook icons mean?](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/icons.htm)

Answer (score 4):

It indicates that the message was digitally signed.